# Python : Using dot to make each sentence a new line in the presence of decimal points

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to have each sentence in a new line. A sentence ends by a `.` . I tried the following code:

```
import re 
text='This text has (15.16 +/- 1.01). And it also has 20.1 km(3) during 4/2002- 
and 1/2018'
text=re.sub('\.', '\n',text)
```

When I try to make each sentence a new line by replacing `.` with `\n` I get four lines instead of two because of the decimal points. I do not need to keep the numbers. I just want to get the alphabetic characters and clean everything else

```
This text has
And it also has during and
```

And solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re

>>> text='This text has 15.16. And it also has 64.6190. twent one guns. hi. 16. 40.5'

>>> print(re.sub('[\d]*\.(?:[\d]*[\.]*[\ ]*)*', '\n',text))


#OUTPUT
This text has 
And it also has 
twent one guns
hi
```

Edit: Do you want to eliminate `+/-`?

```
>>> text = 'This text has 15.16 +/- 1.01. And it also has 64.6190. hi. the tommy is bad. + one-two is negative one.'

>>> print(re.sub('[\d]*\.(?:[\d]*[\.]*[\ ]*)*|[\ ]*[+\-\/]+[\ ]*', '\n',text))



#OUTPUT
This text has 


And it also has 
hi
the tommy is bad

one
two is negative one
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this code work for the example above by if I have  20.27 +/- 1.95 then it will give an additional line for +/-. I changed the original post accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not quite sure what you mean so I'll make an edit with input and about based on your post. Do you also want the regex to delete the `+/-`?

Comment: Yes it would be better to delete everything from the text and just keep the alphabetic characters. I change the post accordingly.

Comment: Got it. I made a new edit. Not e, it will leave extra newlines (\n)'s because it is replacing each query it matches with `\n`. To make it act different I would have to embed the re.subs but your question only asks to replace everything with `\n` for now

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
this one is even simpler

```
text=re.sub(r'(\d*\.)+', r'\n',text)
```

you can adjust regex pattern as you wish, simply:

```
import re 
text='This text has 15.16. And it also has 64.6190.'
text=re.sub(r'\d*\.\d*\.', r'\n',text)

print(text)
```

output:

```
This text has 
 And it also has
```

Explanation: look for any number of digits followed by dot, then again any number of digits followed by dot and replace it with new line